# Standard correct ajax response for login

Tags: php, json, ajax, authentication, response

I'm developing my own PHP framework (which is working quite well, by the way), and now I'm developing a login system. This is no problem, I've got it already working perfectly, I have a database, a registration, login form, logout, etc.

But right now, when you fill up the login form and click "login", ajax is sent, the server (php) verifies the user (username and password) and sends a response back. Now the response is just a number:

0 - Login correct.

1 - Username incorrect.

2 - Username correct, but password isn't.

This works perfectly for its purpose, but I'm sure this is not the correct/professional way, I just invented this. So I'd like to know which would be the right response from a login verification.

For example, many webs use a json response with the "error code", and message, but I don't really know how it works. Also, will this really affect? Or it doesn't matter? What's the real use of this? Security? Mixing with other libraries and services? Or is my current system already fine?

/****** UPDATE ******/

You guys are telling me I shouldn't say that the username/email is right but password isn't. Okay, you are right, I agree and I will correct it, and thanks for your participation and help.

Nevertheless, that's not the question, and the answers should help someone else with my same doubt: the response.

I found this, very useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

And this function (PHP >5.4): http_response_code( $code_number);

Technically it would be:

```
function my_ajax_function( )
{
    //try login

    if (login_correct)
        http_response_code(200);  // 200 = OK
    else
        http_response_code(401);   // 401 = Unauthorized

    // ajax response is independent of the http response
    die("whatever I want");
}
```

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't differentiate between "username incorrect" and "username correct, password incorrect" since this gives potential intruders the confirmation that the login name exists.

Comment: If you tell me that username is correct and password isn't, you just told me I got half my info right. If the username is also an email, you just created a service I can use to validate a bunch of emails against. The next step I've to do is try to contact the guy who owns an account on your site and with a bit of crafty social engineering - I'll get the password soon enough. Therefore, if someone doesn't supply correct credentials, you tell them invalid credentials. Not which one of the two is wrong. The reason you do that is to protect against assholes like me.

Comment: meh, that's not an agreed upon idea though. That's a battle between security and user experience, not a "standard" or "best practice"

Comment: Also, the response shouldn't be a number, it should be DATA (in your case it's a number) accompanied with an HTTP status code. `200` is for `ok`, and 400 - 499 are client error codes. Use HTTP status codes. `422` is usually used when serverside validation fails, you can look up the rest on google.

Comment: Its just as easy to try and signup an email (when emails must be unique)... leaving some other field empty/erroneous on purpose to prevent the actual sign-up ... you get an error return on 'email already in use'. Obscuring login failures is pointless.

Comment: @IncredibleHat don't spread false info. There's a ton of reading material on this subject. You don't tell people they failed the password. You tell them that credentials are incorrect. Reasons have been mentioned. Research before you steer someone to the wrong path.

Answer (score -2):

The ajax reply await to be 200 if all ok, you can return from. Your server a message, and in the success ajax reply your read the reply of server and then if there are something that is wrong you show the details from. Errors, by example you can return 1 for login ok, - 1 for mail. Not exist, and - 2 for password not ok, i edit, you can create a token when you load your form, that will be verified in the ajax call on server later, in this way you add a point of security, you can too in server directly is all is ok redirect to the main page qbere you user is logged

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't response with username is correct but password isn't. This lets hacker know that their half way there. Response should be true or false. They passed authentication or they did not.

The way I handle authentication on my system; if credentials are false, deny access, if credentials are correct, generate session key then move users to next step. Every page request then checks the session key to see if its still valid.

**Update to your Update**; thats a HTTP response code that says the page is not found, ie no file present on server. if you want to send a http response 401 would be it. (401 = Unauthorized)